# Bacula/Bareos disaster recover from scratch using bextract

Tags: backup, bacula

On Bacula/Bareos, document stress the importance of Catalog bootstrap file must be save on somewhere safe, I know Catalog consist of MySQL DB dump and optional included Bacula/bareos config file, but how exactly does anyone recover from scratch in case the whole backup infrastructure is gone?

Is it just install all Bacula/bareos software, then import MySQL and config then fire up Director would do the trick?

Comment: Did you find out the answer to this? I am wondering the same thing? Do you know if it is categorically not possible to restore and/or extract files from a volume without the catalog (e.g. volume files are still in place on disk but the catalog is no longer available)?

Comment: sadly not yet, I am still looking for someone who would be able to answer this.

Comment: i needed to apply part of this today and honestly, there is not a single concise & reliable description of the process on the internet.

Comment: If process not clear, better move on to another project that have good documentation. DR and backup is important and if the process isn't clear, you are asking for trouble when you need to recover data

Answer (score 2):

A bit of an old question, but I'll provide some feed back,

If you've done a mysqldump of the database (or pgdump depending on the backend) you essentially have the catalog in it's full state. I believe that you can simply restore this database to a new server, and restore the old config files (these are not stored in the dump but rather in /etc/bareos). Also, make sure that the same user/password is used for the database user as specified in the bareos-dir.conf file, or else you will not be able to connect to the database. Depending on how your storage devices are setup you may need to mess around with the baroes-sd.conf file.

To answer the other question off the OP, you can use a volume without a catalog. It's a bit cumbersome, but is possible with the following:

http://www.bacula.org/5.0.x-manuals/en/utility/utility/Volume_Utility_Tools.html

For example:

List jobs on a volume: `bls -j -V Full_1-1886 FileStorage1`

List files on a volume: `bls -V Full_1-1886 FileStorage1`

Once you have found the file, or directory (Note wildcard characters are supported) you can extract the file:

`bextract -i restoreFiles -V Full_2-1277 FileStorage2 /tmp/`

Where:

- restoreFiles specifies a file separated with newlines that lists files/directories to restore
- /tmp/ is the destination of the restore